# Unable to make a function call using Django-cron

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-cron

I want to call a method once in a week for which I made an implementation as mentioned here

https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2019/06/24/how-to-setup-a-cron-job-in-django/

I am not sure how it works, but let me explain what I did. I need to call a method as mentioned in folder structure below.

```
proj_application
|
|- myapp
       |
       |-views.py (Method call Inside)
                |- poll_tracked()
```

In views.py,

```
def poll_tracked():
    print('called')
```

In settings.py, I have mentioned

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django_crontab',
]

CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'myapp.views.poll_tracked', '>>' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data.log'))
]
```

After then I run

```
python3.7 manage.py crontab add
python3.7 manage.py runserver
```

When I run crontab -l, I can see,

```
* * * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 /Users/domain/dashboard/proj_application/manage.py crontab run dceca84af9ceab8a4d39d08fa148969f >>/Users/domain/dashboard/proj_application/data.log # django-cronjobs for proj_application
```

A new log file called data.log is generated but the method poll_tracked() mentioned is **not called** and the logs is empty.

Has anyone faced this problem before? If so, Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't pertain the bug you are experiencing, but by having all 5 stars, you will be running your cron job every minute, make sure to change it to ' * * * * 1' to make it run once a week

Comment: @figbar yaa I will do that, but first I need to figure out why the method is not called, if I run every minute.  If you can help me fix that, the next step will be as you told :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try adding `2>&1` at the end, it redirects the error output to the standard output, and might explain why your log file is empty. Also you are missing a space after `>>`

```
CRONJOBS = [
    ('* * * * *', 'myapp.views.poll_tracked', '>> ' + os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'data.log') + ' 2>&1')
]
```

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config.json'. This is the log that I get in data.log now.

config.json is a file which is present outside myapp folder and I have used it in one of the .py files inside myapp. In CRONJOBS, I have mentioned the path as 'myapp.views.poll_tracked' so I think, it searches config.json inside myapp and file not found appears.

Comment: is config.json ever accessed in the poll_tracked() function, or just in other functions inside the python file, which are not being executed by the cron job?

Comment: It is accessed in other functions inside another python file (not even in views.py) which are not being executed by cron job.

Comment: what happens if you execute the function by itself in a shell. (like go into python shell, import myapp, and run poll_tracked). Does it yield the proper output?

Comment: I am unable to import views.py in python console @figbar. I think I have messed up the path somewhere but not sure where, Let me figure out and get back.

Comment: you tried just 'import myapp.views'?. also, it might help to not put your cron jobs in the views.py script, unless its critical that they be there. All of the cron jobs I have written are always in a seperate cron.py or something like that. Its easier to debug, and that way you know nothing else is interfering with it

Comment: >  'import myapp.views'?

Yes, i tried like that. It is searching inside and throwing the error <module 'myapp' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/myapp/__init__.py'> . Making a seperate cron.py file makes sense. i will try it and let you know :)

Comment: are you starting the shell by running 'python' or by running 'python manage.py shell'?

Comment: I tried with python manage.py shell , import myapp.views , then myapp.views.poll_tracked() , yes I could call the intended method.

Comment: ok, I would try to move the function to a seperate cron.py file and try again, its possible something with django is interfering

Comment: I am facing the same error even if I make a separate file or place the file outside my_app folder. I do have a docker-compose file. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement cron on a docker container?

Comment: not sure, sorry. I run all my cron jobs using the 'cron' package, regardless of whether it is a Django project or not. I can direct you to resources for that if you want.

Comment: hey hi, I just have a quick question: When i run crontab -l , the command in crontable looks like this:             


* * * * * /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 /Users/vashwin/dashboard/proj_application/manage.py crontab run 9a34a18f9f32372737d079a2f94ca9a0 >> /Users/vashwin/dashboard/proj_application/data.log 2>&1 # django-cronjobs for proj_application         . Could you let me know how the format should look like?  

       Is it  * * * * * <path to python3.7>. <path to manage.py> and then ?

Comment: mine looks like this, but I dont use the django-cron package. <python path> <file to execute path> >> ~/cron.log 2>&1. * * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/proj/cron.py >> ~/cron.log 2>&1

Comment: so do you give crontab -e, and edit it directly?  If not django-crontab, what do you use?

Comment: well what os do you use? I primarily use ubuntu, and just use the default cron package. yes, I edit it directly with crontab -e

Comment: I use MacOS. I have created a new issue about the progress and detailed description about the same. It would be great if you can help out it that :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62959814/setting-up-crontab-for-my-django-application

Comment: ill check it out